# MySQL query killed - how to prevent that?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash

I'm running a mysql-query from a bash shell which should write the result into a file. The thingy looks like this (simplified a bit):

```
   mysql -uname -ppwd wmap -e "select netpoints.bssid,netpoints.lat,netpoints.lon from netpoints,users WHERE ((users.flags & 1 = 1) AND users.idx=netpoints.userid) OR (netpoints.source=5);" >db/db.csv
```

The query itself is OK and worked fine, but until some time execution of the script fails with

```
   line 1: 11427 Killed
```

So...how can I avoid that the query is terminated this way? The result would be a big amounto f data and the query needs a really long time to execute but that's OK as long as there will be an result.

(Add the command and error message into code tags)

Comment: was it killed manually? is there more debugging info from mysql logs?

Comment: No, it is not killed manually - I guess it happens because the query is too complex/results in too much data

Comment: did you run the command through ssh with time-out issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the entire result set is fetched in memory. If that becomes to much, the mysql client will be killed. You can start the mysql client with the `--quick` option to prevent this:

```
   mysql --quick -uname -ppwd wmap -e  ...
```

Comment: Oh, nice one! Didn't know that :-) I guess I never read the cli's manpage. +1

Answer (score 1):

You might be hitting a timeout in MySQL.  You may want to check your MySQL slow query log to see if that's the case.  If so, you may want to look at optimizing the query if possible, or perhaps increasing the timeouts in MySQL (http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server for info on how to do this).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `LIMIT` to split your query results.

How many rows is your query supposed to return?

It seems that it's going to result in hundreds of thousands (or millions) of rows, consuming too much memory. You can check this with `SELECT count(1) FROM netpoints WHERE <suppressed>;`

If that's not the issue, it's likely that your connection to MySQL is becoming idle and therefore being automatically closed by mysqld. To fix this, you can change your script to issue periodic commands, or increase the MySQL `wait_timeout` configuration.